# Now that the Zend Query has been deprecated what is the best way to post query's in the url?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Reading the manual it seems that the segmant way is the best way to post to post query's to the url now (sql query on multiple fields).  Does anyone have an example I can follow? Or a link?  I get the below message when I use the query option in the module config.  But can't find any info on the new method.

```
 Query route deprecated as of ZF 2.1.4; use the "query" option of the HTTP router's assembling method instead
```

Does the below go in the controller or view?  Would the module config look like

```
'route' => 'foo[/:page][/:sort]'
```

Below is an example I found

```
  $url = $router->assemble(array(
        'name' => 'foo',
    ), array(
        'query' => array(
            'page' => 3,
            'sort' => 'DESC',
        ), 
        // or: 'query' => 'page=3&sort=DESC'
    ));

    // via URL helper/plugin:
    $rendererOrController->url('foo', array(), array('query' => $request->getQuery()));
```

**My View:**

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
 'home/results',
 array(
     'action' => 'results',
     'search_zip'=> '$this->search_zip',
```

**Module Config**

```
'route' => 'results[/:search_zip]
```

Many Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Since use of query string is deprecated, we can use alternate approach to use the query string.

You can add parameter along with route to get/hold the query string value.
But the query string needs to be passed using "/" mark between the  and query string instead of using "?" mark.

**/route-name/key=value&key=value1**

You have to create function that will extract key and value from the query string and return the array, you can add that function in common files so that can be called from any controller where required throughout the project.

You have to use following statement to get the query string value in the controller
$this->params('queryPara')
and passed it to the function which will return the array in "key"=>"value" format of query string.

The routing configurations need to be for the route where you want to use query string.
is

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        '<route-name>' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '<route-name>[/:action][/:queryPara][/]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'queryPara' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-&=]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            ),
        ),
    )),
```

Hope this will be useful

Thanks,
Lakhan Kriplani

Comment: I am still having trouble.  Currently I am trying to post in my view using the setAttributes on the form.  I have updated my code above.  Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Can you specify the code you are using in view with setAttributes